# Rails 5 Redirect From One Directory to Multiple Directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

New to Rails. In Rails 5, I have a lot of pages like `/example_path/view_name`.

I need to split "example_path" into two different directories: "new_path_1" and "new_path_2", with specific views going into new_path_1 and other views going to new_path_2.

I also need to redirect the legacy route to the new route, for example:
`/example_path/view_name_1` needs to redirect to `/new_path_1/view_name_1` 
and
`/example_path/view_name_2` needs to redirect to `/new_path_2/view_name_2`

I've successfully redirected all paths for the first example, for example:

`get '/example_path/:name, to: redirect('/new_path_1/%{name}`.

This works, but it's doesn't allow me to "split" the traffic for the two new paths. It only lets me redirect all legacy "example_paths" to "new_path_1".

How can I split the routes without hard coding?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the constraints option:

```
get '/example_path/:name, to: redirect('/new_path_1/%{name}, constraints: {name: /view_name_1'/}
get '/example_path/:name, to: redirect('/new_path_2/%{name}, constraints: {name: /view_name_2'/}
```

But you would still wind up having to manually define all of the from->to routes, which I am not sure if you qualify that as hard coding. Without having something consistent to split on, you're going to have to manually say which of the old routes goes to which of the new routes.